# How to store accelerometer values for some time and then unregister

Tags: android

From some days i am trying but still all in vain.

i created accelerometer in service and i want to store the acceleromete values for sometime and then unregister.

so i used pendingintent so that will call again.

so therefor i request that how to store the values for at least 10 second and then unregiester.

the follwing is the java;

```
      public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener
              ,SensorEventListener { 
    SensorManager sensor;
     Sensor accelerometer;
     // private FileWriter writer;
      StringBuilder sr;
      }
  @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensor.registerListener(
                 this,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);   




             return START_STICKY;
            }
             @Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


         synchronized (this) {
        try {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2] - 9.8;


            sr.append("" + x).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wait(10000);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //sensor.unregisterListener(this);
        }

       }
    }

       @Override
      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
```

i used synchronized but cann't work .
please any once can help;
I stuck in this if this solve then my final year project will complet.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to handle timer events in android, but I recommend using HANDLER with RUNNABLE.

`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Any code you put here will run after 10 seconds, So you can unregister the sensor here */
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);// 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds.
    }
};
```

`

Comment: And if i campre the value with the values which inside the run() method will it campre with othe values.for example if i want to put

Comment: public run(){ event.values[0];event.values[1]} etc will this campre with in 10 second

Comment: Do you want a repetitive action or you want to run the process for just 10 seconds or the specified amount of time?

Comment: Also, I forget to add that you need to call `runnable.run()` when you want to trigger the runnable. Also, call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` in the on destroy of the activity

Comment: i want to store the values for 10 second to campare with other values then destroy .then after some time the pendingintent call the service and call it again so this process will repeat again and again.but the problem is to hold the accelerometer values for 10 second to camparsion